# Is the decision problems tag needed?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I recently created a new tag: [decision-problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problems). I do believe that this tag is indeed needed because its lack does lead to a lot of somewhat erroneously or misleadingly tagged questions.

For example, a question that has been asked several times over the past decade is how to determine whether a system of linear equations and linear inequalities has a solution over the reals. This is a decision *problem*. This decision problem can be solved using, say, linear programming, which is a decision *procedure*. Usually, such questions have the tag [linear-programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming). However, Fourier-Motzkin could have been used as an alternative decision procedure.

Why are questions on decision *problems* being tagged with the tags corresponding to decision *procedures*? Because this makes little sense to me, I took the liberty of creating [decision-problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problems).

Constructive criticism is most welcome. Thank you for the attention.

Comment: I suspect that most of the users asking questions about systems of linear inequalities are studying the simplex method and wouldn't know from Fourier-Motzkin, so linear-programming is a good tag. I guess decision-problems is OK, provided users don't confuse it with decideability in math logic.

Comment: @Gerry: I believe that decision problems *are* related to decidability from mathematical logic.

Comment: @Asaf, sure – but if beginner questions on the simplex method get mixed in with questions on Godel's theorems then the tag will have limited usefulness.

Comment: @Gerry: Yes, that is my main worry. Not to mention people asking questions like "Help me decide which university to go to"...

Comment: (By the way, thank you, Rodrigo, for taking this topic to meta. I appreciate it very much!)

Comment: Probably some improvements to [the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/decision-problems/info) would be useful. (Ideally coming from somebody who knows the area for which the tag is intended.) Currently it says just: *A decision problem is a question whose answer is either "yes" or "no".* With this description, I would not be surprised if less experienced users used the tag for multiple-choice questions from any area of mathematics - which probably is not the intended use of the tag. (I guess that this is along the lines of Asaf's comment about deciding about choice of university.)

Comment: I think that this might lead to a wider discussion - for which the space in comments under an answer in the long thread would probably not be sufficient. Which is why I [reopened the thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/29843/revisions). (Of course, I might be wrong - I can promise that I won't use dupehammer on the same question more than once.)

Answer (score 3):

Decision problems per se are ubiquitous in mathematics, so some care is needed to identify how such a tag would be useful in organizing *searches* of the Math.SE corpus.

Your lead paragraph asserts that the tag is needed because "its lack does lead to a lot of somewhat erroneously or misleadingly tagged questions."  But the second paragraph doesn't support this claim with its example of using [linear-programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming) for whether "a system of linear equations and linear inequalities has a solution over the reals."  That tag is neither erroneous or misleading for such problems.

The phrase "decision problems" is useful (and familiar) in the context of [computational-complexity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-complexity) of algorithms.  See also [np-complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/np-complete). If the proposed tag were intended to have a wider application, it might cause difficulties like we have with [word-problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problem) and the more technical "word problem in group theory", for which [combinatorics-on-words](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics-on-words) serves as something of a work around.

Comment: With the proposed tag, I can search for all (properly tagged) questions in which LP is used as a decision procedure. Why would I do that? For instance, to flag duplicates, and avoid having each new generation of MSE contributors answering the very same questions over and over again.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Can you give me an example of a Question where linear programming is *not* used as a decision procedure?  Or an example of two linear programming Questions where you see duplication that needs the proposed tag to discover the duplication?

Comment: If finding them were easy! Going through 100s of questions on LP to find a few examples is not productive. But Rome was not built in a day. Tagging can take its time.